# Controller undefined phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

After editing my router config I stumbled across a weird error looking like that *"function `AnyController.init/1` is undefined"*.

```
  scope "/" do
    pipe_through([:require_login])
    resources("/users", UserController,
      only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :delete])
  end

  post("/auth/login", AuthController, :login)
  post("/auth/refresh-token", AuthController, :refresh_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why the error appeared.
I removed the second argument of the [scope/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#scope/4) function which takes the namespace of your controller as parameter.
I was able to fix the error doing the following :

```
scope "/", MyAppWeb do
  pipe_through([:require_login])
  resources("/users", UserController, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :delete])
end

scope "/", MyAppWeb do
  post("/auth/login", AuthController, :login)
  post("/auth/refresh-token", AuthController, :refresh_token)
end
```